# SharedPreferences doesn't seem to work

Tags: android

Here is my `Contacts` activity (my main activity):

```
public class Contacts extends Delegate {

    private static final String TAG = "Contacts";
    public View listContactsView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String restoredText = prefs.getString("token", null);

        if(restoredText == null)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignIn.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ContactListFragment()).commit();
        }

        //new InEventAPI(this).execute("");
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Here is my `SignIn` activity:

```
public SignIn extends Delegate {
    ...
    ...


    public void personSignInDelegate(HttpResponse response, JSONObject result)
    {
        if(response != null && result != null)
        {
            switch(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode())
            {
            case 200:
                try {

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("token", result.get("tokenID").toString());
                    editor.commit();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
                break;
            case 401:
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toastEmailPasswordIncorrect, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Something went wrong!");
        }
    }
```

When I sign in, it commits on `SharedPreferences`, but when I close my app and re-open, the `String` becomes `null` and my `OnCreate` intents to `SignIn` again.

Is something that I'm missing?

Just to avoid doubts, my `Delegate` class:

```
public class Delegate extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected InEventAPI api;

    public Delegate() {}

    public void personSignInDelegate(HttpResponse response, JSONObject result) {};

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely with your use of `getPreferences()`. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29):

> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are
>   private to this activity. This simply calls the underlying
>   getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's
>   class name as the preferences name.

Although both classes extend the `Delegate` class, they are both unique classes with unique names. This means that `getPreferences()` in `Contacts` returns a different SharedPreferenceObject compared to `SignIn`.

Either use `getSharedPreferences(String, int)` 
Eg.
instead of

```
getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

change it to

```
getSharedPreferences ("OneSharedPreference", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or override `getPreferences()` in `Delegate` so it calls `getSharedPreferences()` with a unique name.

Alternatively, if you're not using the default SharedPreferences for anything (this is usually used by any `PreferenceActivity` classes), you can always call

[`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29) and pass in a `Context` instance.

Comment: which one is a better approach?

Comment: In your case I'd use the override because `Delegate` is the parent class of both Activities.